# Save unsent message in Django

Tags: python, django, stack-overflow

When I am about to write a question on Stackoverflow and suddently closes the window it wont delete my message. When I return to the question form it has saved what I wrote last time.

Is it just a normal ajax save with a model field called `is_sent` or something determining when it's sent?

I use Django. How should it be implemented? I guess the question create page is a mix of a `CreateView` and `UpdateView` dependent on whether the user has an unsent message?

Answer (score 0):

While typing in this box and monitoring network activity, I see there is periodically POST to this url

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26750682/editor-heartbeat/answer
```

The POST contains the current content of the textbox. So this could be restored when the page is reloaded.

I imagine questions work through the same mechanism

Comment: But if I make an ajax call to a `CreateView` while typing in the textbox it will create the post with the typed content. When I am done writing my question/comment/answer it will try creating the object again. So I guess the view in which the user creates a new post/question/comment/answer should be an UpdateView which gets the post the user was about to finish?